# Why does nested loop logic not work as expected

Tags: sql, mysql

I am learning SQL from a website and have created the below solution for the problem:

> Show patient_id, first_name, last_name, and attending doctor's
> specialty. Show only the patients who has a diagnosis as 'Epilepsy'
> and the doctor's first name is 'Lisa'
>
> Check patients, admissions, and doctors tables for required
> information.

Table structure

[image]

My solution:

```
SELECT 
  p.patient_id,
  p.first_name,
  p.last_name,
  d.specialty
FROM 
  patients p,
  admissions a,
  doctors d
where
  p.patient_id = 
  (
    select a.patient_id
    where
      a.attending_doctor_id = 
      (  
        select d.doctor_id
        where 
          d.specialty = 'Epilepsy'
          and d.first_name = 'Lisa'
      )
  )
```

But my result I get is empty, no rows are shown.
I'm quite sure my understanding of subqueries is lacking and I don't want to use Join as I want to practice sub-queries.

Why wouldn't the above work by finding the matching rows?

The site uses MySQL I believe.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: *Modern* since 1992 by the way

Comment: … and don’t over complicate things with needless subqueries - just join the tables together in one statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With respect, the website you're "learning" from is not helping you learn if your sample code is what they suggest you do.

Here's how to approach this problem.  You're working with a so-called *relational* database. Each table in it contains *entities* -- in your case, patients, admissions, and doctors.  The entities have relationships between them.  Each patient can have zero or more admissions. And, each doctor can have zero or more admissions.

How can we tell which patients relate to which admissions? By matching `patient_id` values `ON patients.patient_id = admissions.patient_id`.  Similarly, we can tell which doctors relate to which admissions by matching `ON admissions.attending_doctor_id = doctors.doctor_id`.

In the real world of hospital record-keeping, in the USA anyhow, the patient id is called a "medical record number." The doctor id is called a "provider id" or something like that, and the admission id is called an "encounter number" or something like that. Your data model reflects the policy at many hospitals: each current patient has exactly one attending doctor.

Your task is to figure out which patients have Dr. Lisa, with specialty Epilepsy. To do that you need to JOIN the patients entity to the admissions entity, and then JOIN that lot to the doctors entity. And you need to join them ON the appropriate id values.  Like this.

```sql
SELECT 
/* the columns you want in your result set */
       patients.patient_id,
       patients.first_name,
       patients.last_name,
       doctors.specialty
/* the entities and relationships */     
FROM patients
JOIN admissions ON patients.patient_id = admissions.patient_id
JOIN doctors ON admissions.attending_doctor_id = doctors.doctor_id
/* the filters */
WHERE doctors.specialty = 'Epilepsy'
  AND doctors.first_name = 'Lisa'
```

Why might you get zero rows back from this query?  If there's no doctor named Lisa who also (`AND`) works on Epilepsy your query won't find anything. If Lisa has no admissions your query won't find anything.

I hope this helps.

Get a better tutorial. The patients in the hospital you'll work in one day deserve better than what this one is teaching you. Seriously.

Comment: This is great, thanks for the background. For reference the website states I should use JOIN. But it's limiting my sub-query experience, so I am trying to challenge myself by using a SUBQUERY instead

Comment: For completeness I solved it by:
SELECT 
  p.patient_id,
  p.first_name,
  p.last_name,
  d.specialty
FROM 
  patients p,
  admissions a,
  doctors d
where
  p.patient_id = 
  (
    select a.patient_id
    where
      a.attending_doctor_id = 
      (  
        select d.doctor_id
        where 
          a.diagnosis = 'Epilepsy'
          and d.first_name = 'Lisa'
      )
   )